# Kendo Grid: Canceling edit deletes new row

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4ei0zPYiZ1H8AiCTy8B?p=preview) to for the behavior I am experiencing.

If you edit the existing row with id 1, change the text to something else and then press the cancel button, the row is reverted correctly to its previous state.

In order to reproduce my problem you need to:

- Add a new row
- Press the update button to save it.
- Select the row again and press the update button.
- Press the cancel button
- The row disappears!

Even though there are similar questions on this problem, I have yet to find a satisfactory answer.

Some people say that I need to define an id. As you can see from my demo, this does not make any difference, the new row has an id and it still disappears.

There are some suggestions when you are using a remote datasource, but this does not work in my case, I need to use local data.

Finally, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649679/89435) answer. While it does prevent the new row from disappearing, Canceling the row does not revert the data to its old state, it only closes the editor and the data are as they where after the edit.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, no? Have you reported it?

Comment: Yes it does. But as I'm not that experienced with Kendo, I always assume that I did something wrong :-) Of course if no one points out a mistake in my code I will report it as a bug

Comment: you may try with one local variable to store new values and revert back to old values when user clicks cancel(As stated in my answer).

Comment: have you tried the solution i provided?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't tried your solution, and it's been years since I last used Kendo UI

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem. I had it solved by simply calling the cancelChanges() method of the DataSource:

```
..
cancel: function(e) {
            $('#mainGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.cancelChanges();
        },
..
```

Comment: Your solution will work if we don't update the record. If we update the record it will create new records since there is no unique way to refer row. Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/txCRIJsJoAyQcP5IPMti?p=preview

Answer (score 9):

It seems like bug only.But still you could acheive desired output through the below code.

1. I have introduced new variable **tempSavedRecords** and **update
   that variable when you are save or delete the record with kendo
   datasource data.**
2. When the user clicks cancel button **fill the kendo datasource with tempSavedRecords.**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
             var tempSavedRecords = null;
               var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   data: [
                       { id: 1, description: 'Test 1', begin: new Date() }
                   ],
                   schema: {
                       model: {
                           id: 'id',
                           fields: {
                               id: { type: 'number' },
                               description: { type: 'string' },
                               begin: { type: 'date' }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               });    
           $('#grid').kendoGrid({
               dataSource: gridDataSource,
               scrollable: true,
               sortable: true,
               toolbar: ['create'],
               columns: [
                   { field: 'id', title: 'ID', width: 'auto' },
                   { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: 'auto' },
                   { field: 'begin', title: 'Begin', width: 'auto', format: '{0:d}' },
                   { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '172px'}],
               editable: {
                   mode: 'inline',
                   confirmation: false
               },
               save:function(e){
                 updateTempRecords();
               },
               cancel:function(e){
                 if(tempSavedRecords != null){
                  $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(tempSavedRecords);
                 }
                 else{
                  $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.cancelChanges();
                 }
               },
               remove:function(e){
                 $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.remove(e.model)
                 updateTempRecords();
               }
           });
           function updateTempRecords(){
           tempSavedRecords = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
           tempSavedRecords = tempSavedRecords.toJSON();
           }
       });
   ```

Hope this helps.Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tempSavedRecords = null;
    var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            { id: 1, description: 'Test 1', begin: new Date() }
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'id',
                fields: {
                    id: { type: 'number' },
                    description: { type: 'string' },
                    begin: { type: 'date' }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDataSource,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        toolbar: ['create'],
        columns: [
            { field: 'id', title: 'ID', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'begin', title: 'Begin', width: 'auto', format: '{0:d}' },
            { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '172px' }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: 'inline',
            confirmation: false
        },
        save:function(e){
          updateTempRecords();
        },
        cancel:function(e){
          if(tempSavedRecords != null){
           $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(tempSavedRecords);
          }
          else{
           $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.cancelChanges();
          }
        },
        remove:function(e){
          $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.remove(e.model)
          updateTempRecords();
        }
    });
    function updateTempRecords(){
    tempSavedRecords = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    tempSavedRecords = tempSavedRecords.toJSON();
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this actually works perfect. For any future readers -> VERY IMPORTANT <- make sure to include his code for remove event. otherwise ur in for another bug.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the id remains set to its default value. The data source considers such data items as "new" and cancelling them removes them. Once you save a "new" item you need to set its `id` to a non-default value.

Comment: I do set the value of the id, the column is editable. And even if I didn't, I do not understand why canceling the editing of new items should remove them, it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I modified your changes with this [pluckr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbTmV0pWXSlazbXLZMvw?p=preview), and it seems to work.
The only change that I did was to rename 'id' column to 'ided'.

Somehow the 'id' column name, as shown in kendo examples does not work, and to me it seems like a bug.

```
model: {
  id: 'ided',
  fields: {
    ided: { type: 'number' },
    description: { type: 'string' },
    begin: { type: 'date' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this problem by re-setting the data object after add new row.

For example:

```
function onInsertNewRow(dataItem) {
  myDataSource.insert(dataItem);
  myDataSource.data(myDataSource.data());
}
```

By calling data() method you say to grid that the new data asigned is the base data and the new rows are no longer new.

I hope this help you.